# Is it always that lower tree with higher bias but higher tree with higher varaince

Tags: decision-trees, variance, bias

When dealing with bias and variance trade-offs, I always hear that in tree models:

shallow tree = high bias but low variance,

deep tree = low bias but high variance.

Someone may also quote from high reputation class notes to prove it, such as [Here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020spring/bias-variance-error-analysis.pdf).

over fit = high variance

under fit = high bias.

But I feel most of them are miss interpreted. I created a simple simulation to prove that
these claims might be true under some conditions, but NOT always as it. As proved in [no free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)
We can have a situation that a shallow tree has a higher variance than a deep tree.
We can also have cases that a deep tree has a higher bias than a shallow tree.

https://github.com/raingstar/BiasVarianceAnalysis/blob/main/Bias-Variance%20analysis.ipynb

Comment: I think the definitions are swapped: overfit = high variation, underfit = high bias. As far as I'm aware, the statement "shallow tree = high bias but low variance ; deep tree = low bias but high variance" should be understood *in general*, i.e. it tends to be true but not always. So I think you're right saying that it's not always true, but I didn't study this question in detail.

Comment: @Erwan you are right. it is a typo. My understanding is that "shallow tree = high bias but low variance; deep tree = low bias but high variance" is most likely to be true for classification trees, but not as it is for regression trees.